# Aligning img elements horizontally and vertically in the middle of a floating div

Tags: css

I'm looking for a solution to align some images vertically and horizontally in the middle of  a div that has fixed size of 96x96.

There is a solution at [How to make an image center (vertically & horizontally) inside a bigger div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388180/how-to-make-an-image-center-vertically-horizontally-inside-a-bigger-div). But it assumes that we know the sizes of the images. But in my case, the sizes are varying.

Also, I just want to use CSS. I don't want to use a jquery plugin like [this](http://andreaslagerkvist.com/jquery/center/).

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: I've found a solution by using images as background and setting the background-position to 'center center'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Need to center align the image in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370175/need-to-center-align-the-image-in-css/2370521#2370521)

Also adding content related images trough css is considered bad practice. Once the user turns off CSS your content is gone.